# Building a Python Wheel with setuptools throws error Function not implemented: '<package_name>.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'

Tags: python, setuptools

**Problem**

I'm trying to build a Python Wheel using [this guide](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

The issue is that whenever I run `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` it gives an error:

`Function not implemented: '<package_name>.egg-info/dependency_links.txt'`

A screenshot of the error message [can be found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QFuO.png)

**Environment**

The environment is a Jupyter Lab terminal, which runs on an Ubuntu VM (16.04.6 LTS) in Azure.

**Code**

The directory containing the project code looks like this:

project_name/

└── package_name/

└── __init__.py

└── script_name.py

└── setup.py

The __init__.py script contains this line:

```
from . import script_name
```

The setup.py script contains this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="package_name",
    version="0.0.1",
    description="description of the package",
    
    author="Me",
    author_email="me@email.com",
    
)
```

**Tried so far**

So far I've checked:

- That the pip, setuptools and wheel packages are always up to date
- On multiple different VMs I get this error
- On a Windows 10 laptop it works

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this issue was caused by trying to build a wheel from code stored in a mounted storage account on Azure.

The solution we ended up with is to copy the project directory to a temporary location directly on the VM (using [mktemp](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/mktemp.html)) and build the wheel there.

Comment: Could you share some details? I have the same problem.